# Next.js question - why is cookie inaccessible while pre-rendering?

Tags: next.js

I'm making a website using Next.js 13. In my project, Once a user logs in, it saves access token, refresh token from backend server and the user's id in cookie. And whenever authentication is needed, I use the fetch api wrapper below to intercept the request to set an access token to it.

**interceptor (authApi):**

```
"use server";
import returnFetch from "return-fetch";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { getRefreshToken } from "./common";

const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND;
const authApi = returnFetch({
  baseUrl: baseURL,
  interceptors: {
    request: async (requestArgs) => {
      const cookieStore = cookies();
      const accessToken = cookieStore.get("Access");

      if (requestArgs[1] && accessToken) {
        const headers = new Headers(requestArgs[1].headers);
        const contentType = headers.get("Content-Type");
        if (!contentType) {
          headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        }

        requestArgs[1].headers = {
          ...headers,
          "Content-Type": headers.get('Content-Type')!,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken.value}`,
        };
      }

      return requestArgs;
    },
    response: async (response, requestArgs) => {
      if (response.status !== 401) {
        return response;
      }

      const cookieStore = cookies();
      const userId = cookieStore.get("user_id");
      const refreshToken = cookieStore.get("Refresh");
      if (userId && refreshToken) {
        const tokenResponse = await fetch(`${baseURL}/api/user/token-reissue`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({ userId: userId.value }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Cookie: `Refresh=${refreshToken.value}`,
          },
          credentials: "include",
        });

        if (tokenResponse.ok) {
          const { headers } = tokenResponse;
          const accessToken = headers.get("Authorization");
          const setCookieHeader = headers.get("Set-Cookie");

          if (accessToken && setCookieHeader) {
            const { token, options } = getRefreshToken(setCookieHeader);

            cookieStore.set("Access", accessToken);
            cookieStore.set("Refresh", token, options);
          }
        } else {
          throw Error("failed to refresh cookie");
        }
      } else {
        // return await authApi(...requestArgs);
        throw Error("failed to get cookies");
      }

      console.log("complete the reissue of cookies..!");

      return await authApi(...requestArgs);
    },
  },
});

export default authApi;
```

and the **route handler** that **calls the authApi** :

```
import authApi from "@/utils/authApi";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  const res = await authApi("/api/user/me", {
    method: "GET",
  });

  const data = await res.json();
  return NextResponse.json(data);
}
```

**the method** that **sends requests to the route handler**:

```
const publicURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL;


export const getSimpleUser = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${publicURL}/api/user/simple`);
  return response.json();
};
```

it works fine except for page reloads. When I log in and reload the page which contains the getSimpleUser method call,
the authApi doesn't work properly because it can't access the cookie.

I know that whenever the page reloads, next.js server pre-renders the page. So I made the component, which calls getSimpleUser method, render only when its parent component is fully mounted.

**Solution - the UserMenu component render only when its parent component is fully mounted:**

```
'use client';

import React, {Suspense, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import logo from '../../../public/images/logo.png';
import Link from "next/link";
import RegisterNav from "@/components/header/RegisterNav";
import {hasCookie, getCookie} from 'cookies-next';
import UserMenu from './UserMenu';
import AvatarSkeleton from '../ui/skeleton/AvatarSkeleton';
import Skeleton from '../ui/skeleton/Skeleton';

function Header() {
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
       setMounted(true);
    },[]);

    return (
        <header className='my-2'>
            <nav>
                <ul className='flex items-center'>
                    <li>
                        // code skipped 
                    </li>
                    {
                        mounted && hasCookie("user_id") ? (
                            <Suspense fallback={(
                                <div className='flex space-x-1'>
                                    <AvatarSkeleton size="2xs" className='mobile:hidden'/>
                                    <Skeleton sizeClassName="w-[110px] h-[24px] mobile:w-[60px]"/>
                                </div>
                            )}>
                                <UserMenu/> // ***** this is the component that calls the getSimpleUser method *****
                            </Suspense>
                        ) : (
                            <li>
                                <Link href='/login'>Sign in</Link>
                            </li>
                        )
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

But I don't know exactly why the authApi can't access the cookie when next.js pre-renders the page.

Please tell me what I'm missing..

Comment: * I'm Korean so forgive me for any grammar mistakes

Comment: Because the data fetching and code execution occur on the server side.